# Bare Metal - Google

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, bare-metal-server

Can we use Stackdriver for Oracle database monitoring on bare metal solution in GCP?

My Scenario:
I want to install Oracle database on bare metal server. Google does say that all the Google Cloud's services can be used with the bare metal solution. If so, we can use stackdriver for the monitoring. Can you help with how to set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal), we can manage all our custom scripts in the bare metal solution,so stackdriver can be used for Oracle database monitoring on the bare metal solution in GCP.

To [setup](https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal/docs/bms-setup#set_up_routing_between_and) Google Cloud to work with your Bare Metal environment follow the below steps:

1. Create the [VLAN Attachments](https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal/docs/bms-setup#bms-vlan-attachments) for the Cloud Interconnect connection.
2. Specify Advertisements on an existing BGP session using the below command:

   [gcloud compute routers update-bgp-peer](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routers/update-bgp-peer) router-name \
   --peer-name bgp-session-name --advertisement-mode custom
   --set-advertisement-ranges 0.0.0.0/0
3. Create a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal/docs/bms-setup#firewall_setup) in your VPC network on Google Cloud.
4. Create a [Jump Host](https://cloud.google.com/bare-metal/docs/bms-setup#bms-create-jump-host) VM instance on Google Cloud.
5. Login to a Bare Metal Solution server.

For [Monitoring](https://docs.signalfx.com/en/latest/integrations/google-cloud-platform.html#gcp-two) follow the steps:

1. Select a [role](https://docs.signalfx.com/en/latest/integrations/google-cloud-platform.html#part-1-select-a-role-for-the-gcp-service-account) for the GCP service account.
2. Configure GCP.
3. Complete the configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure that we can use it without Anthos installation on the servers.